# Apex date format dd-mm-yyyy but shows mm-dd-yyyy after submit

Tags: date, format, apex

I'm having problems with my date..

I'm having a table which contains the sysdate. sysdate is contained in a hidden field on the apex page which tells me its 17-10-2014. that's what i want it to be. But when I insert the sysdate into the database table it converts the date to 10-17-2014..

My format in the hidden field :
to_char(sysdate, 'dd-mm-YYYY');

Please help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apex is storing a string not a date.  Your database seems to be be set up with the default format 'mm-dd-yyyy'.

I am assuming that the table column has the datatype "DATE".

In your "insert into" clause you need to explicitly cast the string into date, otherwise the database will implicitly cast it using it's own default NLS value.

```
insert into table_name (date_field)
     values (to_date ('17-10-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
```

or

```
insert into table_name (date_field)
     values (to_date (:HIDDEN_FIELD, 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert it in database as format : YYYY-MM-DD